# Watch Html attribute change in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on bootstrap accordion and having 3 sections. I need to change the class based on html attribute change. Is there any way I can check the 'aria-expanded' attribute value and apply to ng-class

```
<a class="collapsed" aria-expanded="true" >
    My Open Tasks <i class="fa fa-sort-asc pull-right" ng-class="aria-expanded? 'fa-sort-desc' : 'fa-sort-asc'"></i>
</a>
<a class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false" >
    My Open Tasks 2 <i class="fa fa-sort-asc pull-right" ng-class="aria-expanded? 'fa-sort-desc' : 'fa-sort-asc'"></i>
</a>
<a class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false" >
    My Open Tasks 3 <i class="fa fa-sort-asc pull-right" ng-class="aria-expanded? 'fa-sort-desc' : 'fa-sort-asc'"></i>
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to create your own attribute directive and assign it to the parent `<a>`, have it watch the attribute and update a scope variable.

Comment: I am working on bootstrap accordion. it's is having 4 sections and based aria expand i need to change the icon up and down @ThinkingMedia

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's a custom directive that, when you add it to your element, will check the element and watch the directive for it.

```
angular.directive("ariaCheck", function(){
        return {
           restrict: "A",
           link: function(scope, element, attributes){
                      scope.$watch(function() {return element.attr('aria-expanded'); }, function(){
                      if(attributes.ariaExpanded){
                          element.addClass("some-class");
                       }
                    }
                 }   
           }
});
```

Then in your html add the directive...

```
<a aria-check class="collapsed"  role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#myopentasks" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" >
                    My Open Tasks <i class="fa fa-sort-asc pull-right" ng-class="aria-expanded? 'fa-sort-desc' : 'fa-sort-asc'"></i>
                </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular way to achieve it, would be to use 2 way binding on that attribute:

```
angular.directive("ariaCheck", function () {
  return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
         ariaExpanded: "="
      },
      link: function (scope) {
          //some logic to set ariaExpanded to false
          scope.ariaExpanded = false;
      }
  }
});
```

Markup:

```
  <a class="collapsed" aria-expanded="true" >
    My Open Tasks 
    <i class="fa fa-sort-asc pull-right" ng-class="{'fa-sort-desc': ariaExpanded, 'fa-sort-asc': !ariaExpanded}"></i>                        
  </a>
```

Make sure that ariaExpanded is: altered within the logic of the directive.
if you need to listen to outside world changes, it might require a more complicated solution.

Comment: Thanks, but it will change area-expanded value in other html mark-up

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve then.
The proper way is to use two way binding here.

Comment: Added image.. Please check

Comment: in that case 'view all' should be on a parent directive, or a controller, and $emit an 'open' event, that the children will listen to.
My choice of implementation would be a taskContainer directive, which creates a list of task directive instances.

Comment: @OlegTikhonov - `aria-expanded` was not a typo.  [Read up on ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques)